# How to find the line number of the end of file in python?

Tags: python

I have 2 questions here:

1) How do I know if it's the end of a file?

2) Once you know that the file has reached the end, how do I get the line number?

To get the line number, I am using the below.

```
def get_block_range (filename, lookupValue):
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if lookupValue in line:
            #print (num)
            return num
```

Comment: What do the lines look like? Are the line "lengths" predictable?  I ask because if so, there's a quicker/smarter approach than crawling every line in the file just to read the final one.

Comment: `num` will be the last line number if the loop gets to the end, `sum(1 for _ in file)` would also get the last line number, do you only want the last line number if you don't find a match or do you want it regardless?

Comment: The line lengths are not predictable. However, please share, that would be useful to know!

Comment: Padriac Cunningham - I would want it regardless. The intention of the lookupValue here is to search for certain string in a text file and process the range of lines in blocks.

Comment: @Vids, so if there is no match what do you want returned? also what are you doing with the result?

Comment: Padriac Cunningham - that's a good question. If there is no match, the program should error out with total number of lines (thinking that it would be helpful for debugging). Using this function, I am trying to get a slice of the file and performing certain steps.

Comment: I use a boolean value as the default value if there is no match, you can check it using the logic in my answer, if val_no is False you know you got no match, `end_no` is always going to return the number of lines in the file regardless. I think using that approach would be a better idea than raising an error as you need the number of lines regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) How do I know if it's the end of a file?

when the for loop stopped, that it the end of the file.

2) Once you know that the file has reached the end, how do I get the line number?

simply return last num variable outside of the forloop...

Code:

```
def get_block_range (filename, lookupValue):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
            if lookupValue in line:
                return num
        return num
```

this way function will return either the number of the first line with lookupValue or the total number of lines.

But if you want to always return the index of the line with lookupValue and total number of lines, you would have to do this:

```
import os 

def get_block_range (filename, lookupValue):
    """
    Returns the index of the first line that contain ``lookupValue``
    and end of the file
    # here the value was at line 941 and the file had 1000 lines. 

    >>> get_block_range('example.txt', 'example')
    (941, 1000)

    :rtype: tuple
    """
    if not os.path.getsize(filename):
        return None, 0

    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lookup_position = None

        for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
            if lookup_position is None and lookupValue in line:
                lookup_position = num
        return lookup_position, num
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as ziddarth's answer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  Except with some explanation.  That's worth something.

Comment: Well I did not really read his answer to the question, the code is the same, but he did not really answered the OPs questions...

Comment: I would not say that the original question asked to always return the number of lines in the file, for that one would have to return tuple...

Comment: What should it return if it reached end of the file though? Is it specified? I think that the behaviour is supposed to be: return the index of the line containing lookupValue or total number of lines. To resolve this discussion OP would have to provide some input/output values.

Comment: I want the line number of the lookupvalue (which the original code is doing) and the line number of the eof regardless of the lookupValue. I am trying to use this code ..getting some errors. I believe the return lookup_position statement should be inside the if statement block and outside (for the total number of lines), correct?

Comment: This could not possibly work for a multitude of reasons, there is unreachable code, what starts as None and is never changed cannot be anything bar None and if you did change the logic to be correct would not return the first match but continually check

Comment: No, sorry my bad, I added some code without checking it, you have a point with the else statement, and and the condition is also wrong...

Comment: Now it works https://gist.github.com/Visgean/49278f2b87839af9a38c and uses only one iteration over the whole file. 

Sorry for flaming here @PadraicCunningham, I was too lazy to write the example file so I made some mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

1. You know you've reached end of the file when you come out of the loop.
2. The num variable is still accessible outside the loop and will contain the last value assigned to it, which is the last line# if there was no match found in the loop.

   ```
   def get_block_range (filename, lookupValue):
       with open(filename, 'r') as f:
           for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
               if lookupValue in line:
                   return num
           return num
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could also take advantage of the file object being it's own iterator if you want the last line number regardless:

```
def get_block_range (filename, lookupValue):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
            if lookupValue in line:
                return num + sum(1 for _ in file), num
        return num, False

# unpack the return values
end_no , val_no = get_block_range ("some_filename", "some_value")
if val_no:
    # found value
else:
    .....
```

If you get no match for the value then it will return the last line number and False. If you do get a match `sum(1 for _ in file)` will consume the rest of the lines so adding it to the current index will give you the total amount of lines and the function will return the total amount and the matched line number respectively. The code will also stop on the first match following the logic in  your own.

Comment: I believe your implementation will fail for empty files, as num will be undefined.

Comment: I will return the first match since there is identity check for lookup_position...